# function that returns a deadpool_postgres::Client returns a Future instead

Tags: rust

I cannot understand this code and error being raised.

```
use deadpool_postgres::{ Config, pool, Client };
use tokio_postgres::NoTls;

pub struct Postgres {
    pool: Pool
}

impl Postgres {
    pub fn new() -> Postgres {
        let mut cfg = Config::new();
        cfg.dbname = Some("deadpool".to_string());
        cfg.manager = Some(ManagerConfig { recycling_method: RecyclingMethod::Fast });
        let pool = cfg.create_pool(NoTls).unwrap();
        return Postgres {
            pool: pool
        };
    }
    
    pub async fn get_client(&self) -> Client {
        if let Ok(client) = self.pool.get().await {
            return Some(client);
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    }
}

async fn main() {
    let pg = Postgres::new();
    let mut client = pg.get_client();
    let stmt = client.prepare_cached("select 1").await;
}
```

The documentation for deadpool_postgres and the IDE tells me that I am getting a Client object in the client variable but the next line is telling me that it is a `impl std:future::Future` instead

```
no method named `prepare_cached` found for opaque type `impl std::future::Future` in the current scope
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `pg.get_client().await;`

Comment: sorry but I did that as well. gives me a Future instead of a Client object.

Comment: figured out my problem. @omer - you were right. I changed it to ```if let Some(client) = pg.get_client().await { let stmt = client.prepare_cached("select 1").await.unwrap(); }```